# Styling rendered mbtiles in offline web-map service

Tags: openlayers, openstreetmap, style, mbtiles

I am building a digital cartography tool that needs to run completely offline. As a basis, I downloaded a `.mbtiles`-file corresponding to the area I want to survey and I am running the excellent [tileserver-php](https://github.com/klokantech/tileserver-php/) on a Raspberry Pi.

I couldn't make it work with the `.mbtiles`-file, so using `mb-util` I unpacked the contents of the `.mbtiles`-file to a folder structure. So far everything seems to be working fine and I get the map served on the browser, however, the resulting rendered tiles look like some kind of wireframe model of a map.

[image: doesn't matter which zoom level]
[image: image always looks "wireframed"]

Not sure now how to get it to render in a nicer, more readable style. I am using OpenLayers in the `index.html`-file of my server, and I thought that's the API that took care of the actual rendering. Ideally, I would like to be able to see the streets, street names and what you would generally come to expect from a web map. What am I missing?

Comment: you need to style your data, for open street map you can use this https://openmaptiles.github.io/osm-bright-gl-style/style-cdn.json

Answer (score 1):

You need to load GL Json stylesheets the integrated viewers for tileserver-PHP may not work use mapbox gl JS OR ArcGIS API for javascript or open layers with GL style plugin/extension. I have an android tile server application serves folder of tiles as XYZ to nearby map clients on same ad hoc or portable Wi-Fi router network

Comment: Thanks, that explains the part about the JSON stylesheets not looking like anything I would expect a stylesheet to look like. So that stylesheet is not for the browser but for the Javascript renderer? Do I understand that correctly?